# node.js store uncaught exceptions in a database

Tags: node.js, synchronization

I am trying to store information about errors into a mysql database using `process.on('uncaughtException', uncaughtException)` so I cannot use async calls since the server shuts down after the `uncaughtException` function is finished so nothing gets saved to the database.

I am using any-db to connect to my database right now but can use anything inside the `uncaughtException` function

Is there any way to send a database query synchronously? or is there a better way to store uncaught exception information into a database?

Comment: You do not want sync database queries, why use Node then? How do you deploy your app? It should not simply shut down, but go to special state instead.

Comment: I am using iisnode so it's not a big deal that node shuts down. This is on an intranet site so performance is not the biggest issue. Is there a better way to store errors in a database?